# how I can load a data from database with row actions in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, uitableviewrowaction

I'm building reminder app, when I swap to the left I can delete and update the reminder; when I press on `edit` button as shown below, it suppose to load data from data base, so I can edit and update the data, but instead it just works like create a new `reminder`.

and how I can resize the row actions.

**ReminderTable.swift**

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in


            if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

                let reminderToDelete = self.fetchResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ReminderData
                managedObjectContext.deleteObject(reminderToDelete)

                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })


        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Edit",handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in

                let st:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc :UINavigationController = st.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Reminder") as! UINavigationController
                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })


        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        return [deleteAction,editAction]
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Reminder" {

            let task = segue.destinationViewController as! Reminder


            let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

            let row = indexpath?.row

            task.reminders = reminders[row!]

        }
    }
```

**Reminder.swift**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    dateTextField.delegate = self
    nameTextField.delegate = self



    if let reminderContent = reminders

    {

        nameTextField.text = reminderContent.name
      dateTextField.text = reminderContent.stringForDate()
        timePick.date = reminderContent.time!
      }  

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        dateFormatter.stringFromDate(reminderContent.date!)

        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mma"
            timeFormatter.stringFromDate(reminderContent.time!)

    }

 func inserte(){

        let storingName = nameTextField.text

        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateTextField.text!)

        if reminders == nil {

            if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {
                reminders = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Reminder", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? ReminderData

                reminders!.name = storingName!
                reminders.date = date
                reminders.time = timePick.date



                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

note that I'm still kinda newbie in iOS development

thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeakC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown us an important piece of the code, what are you doing in Reminder View Controller?

From what I can see you are setting a reminders property on the Reminder VC to the selected row, is this code running as expected?

Once in the Reminder View Controller, I'm guessing you have a form, are you setting the properties in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear?

I would expect to see something like:

```
func viewDidLoad(animated:Bool) {
    Super.viewDidLoad(animated:animated)

    DescriptionTextField.text = reminder.description
    LocationTextField.text = reminder.location
    // ... And so on, filling out each property on your model
}
```

This functionality isn't built in, so you need to build the form and handle the validation of the data and saving into the managed object context (make sure you do this on the same thread)

After looking over the code on github I've updated it and managed to get the reminder to update the changes and show this on the table view.

The main change needed was:

```
// near the top of the file..
var reminder:ReminderData?

// then further down
func update(){

    let storingName = nameTextField.text
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateTextField.text!)


    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext


    if let reminder = reminder {
        reminder.name = storingName
        if let categoryStorage = storingCategory {
            reminder.category = categoryStorage
        }

        reminder.date = date
        reminder.time = timePick.date

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ERROR in update: \(error)")
        }
    }

    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

The main change here is not trying to fetch the reminder again,  you have passed the managedObject(Reminder) over to the editVC so dont need to fetch it again. so you just update the values and then save.

Also when you was fetching you was fetching all records. If you want to do it this way you would likely pass over the reminder ID to the Reminder VC and then load it by ID, modify and save. in order to do this you'd need to add an ID field and update your fetch to include a predicate, but for now you dont need it.

Comment: I've updated my post look above at **Reminder.swift** , besides my app work just fine by pressing on cell, the data it's just loaded fine with no problem; but by row action it just create a new reminder

Comment: look at **Reminder.swift**, I've updated the code again again, I believe the fault is in **ReminderTable.swift**

Comment: are any errors been thrown? after you have edited the reminder object in Reminder.swft and you return to the table, are you reloading the data? your code in tableview looks ok to me. The table's job is to just render the data, its your job to fetch it, edit it and reload it when required

Comment: the code work just fine, I just haven't posted the entire code, and I believe you misunderstood my question; let me rephrase my question

when I link table cell with table view in traditional way, the data is loaded with no problem, but I want the user to be able to edit Reminder only by swapping the cell to the left and then press on edit like in [photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HeakC.png), once the user press on edit, the Reminder view should be loaded with data the stored in database 

but I failed to do that, how I can solve this problem?


am really  sorry for causing you a headache

Comment: only posting part of the code is making this a longer process as i cannot see the whole story. what your trying to do is fairly easy for someone that has done it before and if we could see the full code we would likely spot your error fairly quickly. The process should be that you swipe left, click edit, this segues to the edit reminder screen in which you load the data into the fields from the model. then your user edits this data and clicks some sort of save button or something and then you copy the details from the input fields into the model again to update it, save changes, close view

Comment: then on returning to the table view make sure you load the data again from core data (as its changed)

Comment: if you want, I can load the project on the github and give you the link, to see what real problem

Comment: sure, do that and I'll advise where the issue is

Comment: I have it working on my machine, I've updated the answer above with some advice

Comment: before seeing your answer, have you tried to swap the cell to the left and pressed on blue button?

have the date been loaded when the view is displayed?

Comment: well thanks a lot :)

sorry for causing you unwanted troubles

Comment: your welcome :) If this answers your question please mark it as the answer, otherwise other people would continue to try and resolve it.